# wit.ai 'Only if..' not working

Tags: wit.ai

I am new in wit.ai. I'm confused with it. I have few questions:

1. how works   Actions: 'Only if..' and 'Always if...'
   simply I have 2 entities: 'Hi' and 'Botname',I have 2 stories: when say 'Hi' wit answers 'answer1', when say 'Botname', wit answers 'answer2'. It's Ok, but when combined 'Hi Botname', I want wit to answer 'answer1', but I can't echieveit without adding story.   I try to add in Actions ->'Answer2'-'Only if..' 'doesn't have' ->'Hi', but still it answers 'Answer2' and I don't understend why :)
2. second question I sometimes don't get adequate answer from wit and I don't know how to avoid such cases. For example: entity 'constitution' and in 'understending' when writing 'station' wit gets 'constitution', this two words are different. and what to do? please, help with it.

Answer (score 1):

1. To the *first* question, I'd suggest that rather than trying to use the keyword and free-text format of entities, you define and assign a ***trait*** entity which will not necessarily try to match the exact word, but the feeling of the sentence.

> ### For example
>
> Given the situation above, if you were to train an intent
> called "greeting" to recognize all sentences with "Hi" in it as
> greetings, then the result of "Hi Botname" will continue to be the
> result of Hi. Also, if you're going to be using branching, enitites
> will have to be defined as *trait* entities in either case.

2. To the *second* (And this will help with the first), you just have to spend some time training the bot to understand. You can't rush the brush. You'll have to feed it some examples before it can understand the difference in the words, and start to pick those differences up in future words.

The Wit Bot engine was released only a little while ago, so we're all learning it now, but I hope I  could help you with the little knowledge I've gained.

Comment: Thank you for nswering. it helped me

Comment: No problem. Was it the answer you were looking for?